# Removing data validations from Excel File programmatically

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel file with data validation on each header. Data validations are of two types

1. Any value
2. List

I have a requirement where I have to delete some columns, which in turn also means delete the corresponding data validation. But in my code, columns are deleted successfully but the validations remain as it is.

Below is the snippet of code:

```
package org.example;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddressList;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.CalculationChain;
import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class RemoveDataValidations {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\Test.xlsx";
    int columnToRemove = 2; // Replace with the actual column index to be removed

    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
         Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis)) {

        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); // Assuming the first sheet, change as needed

        // Remove data validations for the specified column
        for (int i = sheet.getDataValidations().size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            DataValidation dataValidation = sheet.getDataValidations().get(i);
            CellRangeAddressList addressList = dataValidation.getRegions();
            if (addressList != null && addressList.getCellRangeAddresses()[0].getFirstColumn() == columnToRemove) {
                sheet.getDataValidations().remove(i);
            }
        }

        // Remove the column (shift columns to the left)
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowIndex++) {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
            if (row != null) {
                Cell cellToRemove = row.getCell(columnToRemove);
                if (cellToRemove != null) {
                    row.removeCell(cellToRemove);
                }
            }
        }

        // Update the sheet to reflect the changes
        sheet.shiftColumns(columnToRemove + 1, sheet.getRow(sheet.getFirstRowNum()).getLastCellNum() - 1, -1);

        // Save the modified workbook
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath)) {
            workbook.write(fos);
        }

        System.out.println("Data validations removed successfully.");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Also, attaching the snippet of excel file for the reference.
[image]

In the above image, let's say I have to remove column named 'Col 5', the list validation implemented for Col 5 should be deleted as well.

Comment: `Sheet.getDataValidations()` creates a fresh `ArrayList` from underlying Excel sheet every time it gets called. Removing items from that list has no effect to the underlying Excel sheet. Therefore, I'm afraid that removing data validations is not supported yet.

Comment: @AxelRichter I just checked the implementation of getDataValidations() and yes, it creates a new arraylist everytime. Do you have any suggestion how can I remove data validations ?

Comment: "any suggestion how can I remove data validations": Write a method to do so using `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTDataValidations` got from `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorksheet` of `XSSFSheet`.